# jQuery Datatables - Custom grouping by grouped label

Tags: jquery, datatables

[image]

I am using similar code below to do grouping but
unable to find a sample of my desired output.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [
        { "visible": false, "targets": 2 }
    ],
    "order": [[ 2, 'asc' ]],
    "displayLength": 25,
    "drawCallback": function ( settings ) {
        var api = this.api();
        var rows = api.rows( {page:'current'} ).nodes();
        var last=null;

        api.column(2, {page:'current'} ).data().each( function ( group, i ) {
            if ( last !== group ) {
                $(rows).eq( i ).before(
                    '<tr class="group"><td colspan="5">'+group+'</td></tr>'
                );

                last = group;
            }
        } );
    }
} );
```

Comment: You may use RowGroup functionality of the data table. Please go through this link. https://datatables.net/extensions/rowgroup/

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Pre-sorting data resolved this challenge.